# How to picture two marriages in genealogytree

Tags: genealogytree

```
\begin{genealogypicture}[timeflow=left,
    processing=database,
    database format=full marriage below,
    date format=d/m/yyyy,
    tcbset={male/.style={colframe=blue,colback=blue!5},
      female/.style={colframe=red,colback=red!5}},
box={fit basedim=7pt,boxsep=2pt,segmentation style=solid,
halign=flush left,before upper=\parskip1pt,
\gtrDBsex,drop fuzzy shadow,
if image defined={add to width=25mm,right=25mm,
underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\path[fill overzoom image=\gtrDBimage]
([xshift=-24mm]interior.south east) rectangle (interior.north east);
\end{tcbclipinterior}},
}{},
},
edges=rounded,
  ]
sandclock
{
  child{
    p{male,
      name=Willy Otto Alfred Scholz,
      birth={1889-02-11}{Moabit, Berlin},
      marriage={1910-11-30}{Heilandkirche, Berlin},
      death+={1914-08-23}{Vedin vor Namur, Belgien}{killed},
      comment={Reservist im Infanterie-Regiment No. 93}
    }
    g{female,
      name={\bf Therese Margarete Agnes Emma Hille},
      birth={1887-09-10}{Dalldorf},
      marriage={1910-11-30}{Heilandkirche, Berlin},
      %marriage={1920-04-30}{Berlin},
      death={1961-09-12}{Hamburg}
    }
    c{female,
      name=Gerda Senta Margot Ilse Scholz,
      birth={1911-06-16}{Berlin}
    }
    c{male,
      name=Werner Karl August Albert Scholz,
      birth={1914-07-12}{Berlin},
      death={1978-08-03}{Hamburg}
      }
    union{
      p{male,
      name=Heinrich Paul Popp,
      birth={1895-01-18}{Schiffbek},
      death={1967-08-31}{Hamburg},
      marriage={1920-04-30}{Berlin},
      comment={Kaufmann}
      }
      c{male,name=Waldemar Popp}
    }
  }
  parent{
    g{male,
    name=Hermann August Albert Hille,
    birth={1858-08-24}{},
    }
  }
  parent{
    g{female,name=Berta Schwarz}
    }
}
\end{genealogypicture}
```

I would like the 2 dates of marriage at Therese's box. I can't find a solution in the manual,

Comment: Welcome to TEX S.E. Please correct your MWE. Add four spaces in front of each code line to have your code properly displayed. Moreover your MWE should be fully compiliable, that is with `documentclass`, packages needed to compile your MWE and `\begin{document}`, `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

There's not yet a fancy command `\declareNewEvent` (perhaps there will never be?), so to get the second marriage shown, you have to add several commands inspired from the package and declare a new event called for instance "secondMarriage".

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
%-------------------------------------%
% enter in the @ mode
\makeatletter
% add the new event "secondMarriage"
\gtr@db@new@event@store{secondMarriage}%
% declare a new Database format based on the original one you used to show the new event.
\gtrDeclareDatabaseFormat{full marriage below with second marriage}{}{%
  \gtrPrintName%
  \begin{gtreventlist}%
    \gtr@list@event{birth}%
    \gtr@list@event{baptism}%
    \gtr@list@event{floruit}%
    \gtr@list@event{death}%
    \gtr@list@event{burial}%
  \end{gtreventlist}%
  \gtr@print@infolist%
  \gtr@ifmarriagedefined{%
    \tcbline\begin{gtreventlist}%
      \gtr@list@event{engagement}%
      \gtr@list@event{marriage}%
      \gtr@list@event{divorce}%
      \gtr@list@event{secondMarriage}% this line is the only one added
    \end{gtreventlist}%
  }{}%
}
% leave the @ mode
\makeatother
% declare the symbol used in prefix.
\gtrset{/gtr/event prefix/secondMarriage/.initial=\gtrsymMarried}
%-------------------------------------%
\begin{document}
\begin{genealogypicture}[timeflow=left,
    processing=database,
    database format=full marriage below with second marriage,% don't forget the new format!!!
    date format=d/m/yyyy,
    tcbset={male/.style={colframe=blue,colback=blue!5},
      female/.style={colframe=red,colback=red!5}},
box={fit basedim=7pt,boxsep=2pt,segmentation style=solid,
halign=flush left,before upper=\parskip1pt,
\gtrDBsex,drop fuzzy shadow,
if image defined={add to width=25mm,right=25mm,
underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\path[fill overzoom image=\gtrDBimage]
([xshift=-24mm]interior.south east) rectangle (interior.north east);
\end{tcbclipinterior}},
}{},
},
edges=rounded,
  ]
sandclock
{
  child{
    p{male,
      name=Willy Otto Alfred Scholz,
      birth={1889-02-11}{Moabit, Berlin},
      marriage={1910-11-30}{Heilandkirche, Berlin},
      death+={1914-08-23}{Vedin vor Namur, Belgien}{killed},
      comment={Reservist im Infanterie-Regiment No. 93}
    }
    g{female,
      name={\bf Therese Margarete Agnes Emma Hille},
      birth={1887-09-10}{Dalldorf},
      marriage={1910-11-30}{Heilandkirche, Berlin},
      secondMarriage={1920-04-30}{Berlin},
      death={1961-09-12}{Hamburg}
    }
    c{female,
      name=Gerda Senta Margot Ilse Scholz,
      birth={1911-06-16}{Berlin}
    }
    c{male,
      name=Werner Karl August Albert Scholz,
      birth={1914-07-12}{Berlin},
      death={1978-08-03}{Hamburg}
      }
    union{
      p{male,
      name=Heinrich Paul Popp,
      birth={1895-01-18}{Schiffbek},
      death={1967-08-31}{Hamburg},
      marriage={1920-04-30}{Berlin},
      comment={Kaufmann}
      }
      c{male,name=Waldemar Popp}
    }
  }
  parent{
    g{male,
    name=Hermann August Albert Hille,
    birth={1858-08-24}{},
    }
  }
  parent{
    g{female,name=Berta Schwarz}
    }
}
\end{genealogypicture}
\end{document}
```

Therese has now her second marriage shown:

[image]

Comment: Thomas Sturm accepts reasonable pull requests (or at least has accepted some of mine :) -- floruit event and Danish translation) so perhaps it is an idea for one? https://github.com/T-F-S/genealogytree